# python /SFTP - переместить каталог на удаленный сервер

Tags: python, sftp

SFTP

```
ftp.put_d(discharge, './'+directory)
```

Таким образом перемещаю каталог на удаленный сервер.
Затем вынужден удалять содержимое каталога и сам каталог на локальном сервере

```
for fl in glob.glob(discharge+'*'): #Удаляем файлы
    os.remove(fl)

s.rmdir(discharge)
```

Вопрос в том, предусмотрена ли в SFTP. Перенос каталога, именно перенос, а не его копирование. Чтобы просто перемести и затем не прибегать к лишним операциям на удаление файлов на локальном сервере.

Comment: помогло снять вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно https://opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sftp&category=1&russian=0 - нет, не предусмотрено.